# jQuery can't find closest p

Tags: javascript, jquery

The task should be pretty simple: starting from my input field, find the closest p and change its style.

Only thing is: I can't find my p...

```html
<p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Email" class="control-label col-md-2">Email</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="email" value="" name="Email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</p>
```

And this is the javascript code to find the p element

```js
$('[name=Email]').closest("p").css('background-color', 'red')
```

`closest("p")` returns nothing.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: What is the length of `$('[name=Email]')`?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 length is 1

Comment: you'd be better off using an ID field too, then just using `$('#Email')`.  The `name` field is only really useful for form submission and not so much for DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

You cannot have a `<div>` inside a `<p>`. The div start tag implicitly ends the paragraph element. The paragraph end tag is then ignored because there isn't an open paragraph for it to close.

Your markup is equivalent to:

```
<p></p>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Email" class="control-label col-md-2">Email</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="email" value="" name="Email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This means that the input is also not inside the paragraph. So when you look for the closest ancestor of the input that is a paragraph, there isn't one.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the fastest solution to any of my questions here on stackoverflow